# Custom social buttons with counters?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, user-interface, twitter

How would one go about creating custom social buttons (specifically Post to Twitter, Facebook, Stumblepon, Reddit) - with counters. The buttons need the same consistent styling as part of a design and we ideally don't want to use the out-of-the-box ones as such.

Creating custom buttons is easy - but custom counters I'm not sure about. How could this be achieved?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 11):

A number of social sites provide [APIs methods](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2347575) for getting the share count for a specific URL. Some of the API methods are internal and not publicly supported.

- LinkedIn - http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://news.ycombinator.com
- Facebook - http://graph.facebook.com/http://news.ycombinator.com

Twitter has [removed](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform) their undocumented API endpoint.

- <s>Twitter - http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://news.ycombinator.com</s>

Comment: This is definitely a clean way to do what you require; just be sure to account in your error handling for the possibility that the API methods could change or disappear completely.

Comment: I've got some PHP implementations for Twitter, Facebook and Reddit on my blog: http://dan.cx/blog. The source code is on Github if you want to take a look at it: https://github.com/Daniel15/Website/tree/master/application/classes/social

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm very interested in your method. However, the github link is dead. Would you mind sharing it again?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same with Google+ ?

Comment: There is a dirty workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11744589/26406 and an open feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=420

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about the Facebook API, but the Twitter API allows you to custom style the buttons. 
You can find it under the heading "Build Your Own Tweet Button" which is at the bottom of the following page:

https://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button

Alternatively you could use Javascript to grab the button node and attach the count details to your own  buttons.