# Get Number of +1s for Google Plus Local Business Page

Tags: php, ajax, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-one

Okay so I know I can get the number of +1s for a Google Plus page based on its website URL, however I would like to get the number of +1s for my Google Plus Local Business page, preferably using either AJAX (jQuery AJAX is fine) or PHP
Any suggestions would be great

Comment: Repeat question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853342/how-to-get-google-1-count-for-current-page-in-php?rq=1

Comment: That method works fine for standard Google Plus pages but not the Local Business ones